# After Django update to 1.8.2 : 'OneToOneRel' object has no attribute 'unique_for_date'

Tags: django, django-models

[image: Screen Shot]

I am getting this error after I update Django from 1.7x to 1.8.2

The affected line is

Phy = models.OneToOneField(User)

The same applies to many to many fields.

Comment: You need to let us know your models code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Django Rest Framework as well as Django.

Support for the Django 1.8 alpha was added in 3.0.4, and at the time of writing, the latest version is 3.1.3.